# sum of every nth slice in an 3D array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array, 120 by 160 by 5840.
Now I want to take sum/mean of every 8th slice along third direction/dimension, the result should be "120 by 160 by 730". I can make it using for loop but is there any easy and quick way.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post an MCVE. You basically want to reshape the dimension of interest, but it's up to you to decide how to do that.

Comment: Please add language and array package tags